# Is it possible to use kubectl run --overrides for adding new configs instead of overriding whole configuration?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a `kubectl run` command that looks like this:

```
kubectl --context ${CONTEXT} -n ${NAMESPACE} run ${POD_NAME}         \
    --env VARIABLE1=${VARIABLE1}                                                         \
    --env VARIABLE2=${VARIABLE2}                                                         \
    --image ${DOCKER_IMAGE}:${IMAGE_TAG}                                                         \
    --image-pull-policy=Always --restart=Never --rm --wait --attach                              \
    --command -- sh -c "./my-srcipt.sh"
```

At some point I ended up needing to handle SecurityContext for this pod. I saw this `--overrides` option and tried to use it like this:

```
kubectl --context ${CONTEXT} -n ${NAMESPACE} run ${POD_NAME}         \
    --env VARIABLE1=${VARIABLE1}                                                         \
    --env VARIABLE2=${VARIABLE2}                                                         \
    --image ${DOCKER_IMAGE}:${IMAGE_TAG}                                                         \
    --image-pull-policy=Always --restart=Never --rm --wait --attach                              \
    --overrides="{
                    \"apiVersion\": \"v1\",
                    \"spec\": {
                      \"securityContext\": {
                          \"runAsUser\": 1234,
                          \"runAsGroup\": 1234,
                          \"fsGroup\": 1234
                      },
                      \"containers\": [
                        {
                          \"image\": \"${DOCKER_IMAGE}:${IMAGE_TAG}\",
                          \"name\": \"${POD_NAME}\",
                          \"securityContext\": {
                            \"capabilities\": {
                              \"drop\": [\"ALL\"]
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }"                                                                              \
    --command -- sh -c "./my-srcipt.sh"
```

However, looks like `--overrides` option replaces whole pod configurations given in `kubectl run`'s other options (including --command and --env).

Is there a way to add those configs without overriding everything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I was able to resolve my problem by adding `--override-type strategic` option to my `kubectl run` command.